# Is there a simpler way to show and hide many divs using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to show and hide divs using jQuery by other simple method. This code is just for testing and it has a lot of divs to hide and show, so it will get very long when I add all the divs.

**code html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
         <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
              <option>select</option>
               <option value="1">choose1</option>
               <option value="2">choose2</option>
         </select>
        </div>

      <div class=" col-md-12" id="divt">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="titre">type</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-md-4">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="1" name="type" checked="checked">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="o">offer</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-md-4">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="2" name="type">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="d">request</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      
    
    <div class="form-group" id="divb">
      <label>business <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="entreprise" id="entreprise" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group" id="divp">
     <label>Poste <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
          <select class="form-control" name="poste">
              <option></option> 
              <option>Plien temps</option> 
              <option>Mi-temps</option> 
          </select>
    </div>
     
    <div class="form-group" id="divn">
      <label>Nom Piece <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="piece" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
 $(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
      let category_id = $(this).val();
    if(category_id === "1"){
      $("#dive").hide();
      $("#divn").hide();
      $("#divt").hide();
      $("#divp").show();
      $("#divb").show();
    }else if(category_id === "2"){
      $("#dive").show();
      $("#divn").show();
      $("#divt").show();
      $("#divp").hide();
      $("#divb").hide();
    }else{
      $("#dive").show();
      $("#divn").show();
      $("#divt").show();
      $("#divp").show();
      $("#divb").show();
    }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: You should separate your groups of ids into classes that would reduce code. For example, #dive, #divn, #divt seem to be part of one group and #divp and #divb another (interpreting from when they show / hide together)

Comment: What @Redseb says! (I'm out of comment votes for the day so can't upvote it, but that is the right action!). That is exactly what classes are meant for. You only use ids when you need to target elements individually. When you need to target multiple elements, classes are much more appropriate and *much* easier to maintain!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are going to do this based on id rather than classes (which is what classes are designed for), you have to add every id manually into your jQuery code. So if you have lots of divs that's a lot of ids to maintain! Using a class means you just have 2 classes to manage which is much simpler, and you don't need to change the jQuery at all - just apply the appropriate class to each div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your DIVs are also in the `form-group` class. So you could first hide all of them, then just show the ones specific to the selection.

```
$(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
  let category_id = $(this).val();
  $(".form-group").hide();
  if (category_id === "1") {
    $("#divp,#divb").show();
  } else if (category_id === "2") {
    $("#dive,#divn,#divt").show();
  } else {
    $(".form-group").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better you use class instead of id to show/hide
Showing/Hiding divs, you are grouping those into visible blocks now so having class names shared between divs work the better.

Id is used more when you need to get exactly one element.
Also having id like "divt" is meaningless as that naming is not intuitive.
It will be better to update ids to meaningful names too.

```
<div class="container">
   ...
      <div class=" col-md-12 group-1" id="divt">...
        </div>
      
    
    <div class="form-group group-2" id="divb">...
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group group-2" id="divp">...
    </div>
     
    <div class="form-group group-1" id="divn">...
    </div>
 </div>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
 $(document).on('change', '#category_id', function() {
      let category_id = $(this).val();
    if(category_id === "1"){
      $(".group-1").hide();
      $(".group-2").show();
    }else if(category_id === "2"){
      $(".group-1").show();
      $(".group-2").hide();
    }else{
      $(".group-1").show();
      $(".group-2").show();
    }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I agree that classes are the better option for this. If you could edit your answer to include a short explanation *why* it is better (and fix the problem with 2 `class` attributes on the divs!) it would make your answer much more useful - not just to the OP but also to other users.

Comment: Thank you @FluffyKitten
I updated the code to fix 2 class attributes problem.

Comment: Don't forget the explanation :) Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't give any explanation and therefore are not as useful as they should be.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1: jQuery can combine multiple selectors using commas:

```
$("#dive,#divn,#divt").show();
```

2: You could use classes to represent logical groups, say "cat1" for those which are shown with category 1 and "cat2" for those with category 2:

```
<div id="dive" class="category cat2"></div>
<div id="divn" class="category cat2"></div>
<div id="divp" class="category cat1"></div>
<div id="divb" class="category cat1"></div>
```

Then your code is

```
$(document).on("change", "#category_id", function() {
   let category_id = $(this).val();
   if (category_id == 1) {
      $('.category').hide();
      $('.cat1').show();
   } else if (category_id == 2) {
      $('.category').hide();
      $('.cat2').show();
   } else {
      $('.category').show();
   }
});
```